# Pygame rotation

Tags: python, pygame, sdl, python-3.4

I'm implementing scorched earth in python 3.4 using pygame. My problem is that I don't know how to effectively implement barrel so that I can easily rotate it.
I already tried using rect and image but I can't rotate any of them. 
Is there a better way or I should just try with image or rect?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate images using [pygame.transform.rotate](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate). I suggest using a cache for the various degrees you need.

Comment: I played a little while with pymunk and that doesn't really solve the initial problem of rotating rectangle preserving its shape.

Comment: Ah, I might have misunderstood. If what you are after is freely rotatable images, you might consider pyglet instead, because it uses OpenGL and you can use whatever affine transformation (rotation, scaling, shearing...) on it. Or use http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate - but I'm not sure how good looking the results are.